# Artin approximation vs implicit function theorem in the class of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I am not an algebraist so my question might be stupid. I am doing mainly complex analysis and recently I was informed about the existence of Artin's theorem and it sounded like it could be of interest to me. I have found a survey on the subject and I started reading it. Here's the [link](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~rond/Artin_survey.pdf).

So to the actual theorem (section 1.1)

> Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field of characteristic 0 and let $f(x,y)$ be a vector of convergent power series in two variables $x$ and $y$. Assume given a formal power series $\hat{y}(x)$ vanishing at 0,
>   $$f(x,\hat{y}(x))=0.$$
>   Then for any $c\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a convergent power series solution $\tilde{y}(x)$
>   $$f(x,\tilde{y}(x))=0$$
>   which coincides with $\hat{y}(x)$ up to degree $c$,
>   $$\hat{y}(x)\equiv \tilde{y}(x) \mbox{ mod }x^c. $$

I really care only for the case where $k=\mathbb{C}$. Using the implicit function theorem for some analytic $f$ we get the existence of an analytic solution as long as the Jacobian is invertible at 0. If on the other hand the Jacobian is not invertible then we generically get some king of branching and this means that there is no formal solution in powers of $x$ that solves the equation. So in that sense I don't see how Artin's theorem is stronger than the implicit function theorem in the analytic setting.

Is this true or do I miss something? By the way I don't know what happens when we considering other fields and I don't imply that the theorem is trivial or useless.